# Normal Subgroups in the Center of a Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, automorphism-group

This is from Dummit and Foote *Abstract Algebra*, page 134.

> If $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$, and $H \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, then we can deduce from the automorphism group that $N_G(H) = C_G(H)$.

I understood this, since $H$ has an element of order 1 and 2, and they have to map to elements of the same order. So the Aut$(H) = 1$. From this, we know $1 = \frac{N_G(H)}{C_G(H)}$, so   $N_G(H) = C_G(H)$.

> If in addition, $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $H \subset Z(G)$

How do we know this?

Comment: A key observation, I suppose, is that $H=N_G(H)$ if $H$ is normal.

Comment: Let $x \in H$ be the unique nontrivial element of the normal subgroup $H  \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$. Let $g \in G$ be any element. What can you say about $g x g^{-1}$?

Comment: @Shaun if $H$ is normal, isn't $N_G(H) = G$?

Comment: Yes indeed, @Jess; thank you for correcting me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N$ is normal, $N_G(H) = G$. Then, since $N_G(H)= C_G(H)$, it follows that $C_G(H)=G$. This,by definition, means that $H \subset Z(G)$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll turn my comment into a "hint answer":

Let $x \in H$ be the unique nontrivial element of the normal subgroup $H  \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$. Let $g \in G$ be any element. What can you say about $g x g^{-1}$?